# See all local history in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just did a `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and my Source Control > Changes just went from showing 3 (maybe 4) files to 1.

I've manage to find 1 of those files and Timeline shows the edit I made 1 hour ago.

Is there any way to see a list of changes ordered by time?

Like this: [image]

but for all files instead of the currently opened file.